# How to do matrix multiplication without restricting the dimensions of the input matrices to be multiples of the block size?

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication

I need to **modify the code to remove the restriction that the dimensions of the input matrices must be multiples of the block size**, but have no clue how to do this.

The guide I am following says to make changes to the *main* method in order to do this, but as far as I am aware, the code in *main* simply populates the array and calls the kernel.

Below is my code, it is a basic Matrix Multiplication calculator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <cuda.h>
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16

// Matrices are stored in row-major order
typedef struct {
int width;
int height;
float* elements;
} Matrix;

__global__ void MatrixMultKern(const Matrix A, const Matrix B, const Matrix C) {
    // Calculate the column index of C and B
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    // Calculate the row index of C and of A
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if ((row < A.height) && (col < B.width)) {
        float Cvalue = 0;
        // each thread computes one element of the block sub-matrix
        for (int k = 0; k < A.width; ++k) {
            Cvalue += A.elements[row * A.width + k] * B.elements[k*B.width + col];
        }
        C.elements[row * C.width + col] = Cvalue;
    }
}

// Matrix multiplication - Host Code
// Matrix dimensions are assumed to be multiples of BLOCK_SIZE
void MatrixMult(const Matrix h_A, const Matrix h_B, Matrix h_C)
{
    // Load A and B into device memory
    Matrix d_A;
    d_A.width = h_A.width; d_A.height = h_A.height;
    size_t size = h_A.width * h_A.height * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_A.elements, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_A.elements, h_A.elements, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    Matrix d_B;
    d_B.width = h_B.width; d_B.height = h_B.height;
    size = h_B.width * h_B.height * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_B.elements, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B.elements, h_B.elements, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Allocate C in Device memory
    Matrix d_C;
    d_C.width = h_C.width; d_C.height = h_C.height;
    size = h_C.width * h_C.height * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_C.elements, size);

    // Invoke Kernel
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 dimGrid(d_B.width / dimBlock.x, d_A.height / dimBlock.y);
    MatrixMultKern<<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>>(d_A, d_B, d_C);

    // Read C from Device to Host
    cudaMemcpy(h_C.elements, d_C.elements, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Free Device Memory
    cudaFree(d_A.elements);
    cudaFree(d_B.elements);
    cudaFree(d_C.elements);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Matrix A, B, C;
    // Read Dimensions of A and B
    A.height = atoi(argv[1]);
    A.width = atoi(argv[2]);
    B.height = A.width;
    B.width = atoi(argv[3]);

    //Allocate memory
    A.elements = (float*)malloc(A.width * A.height * sizeof(float));
    B.elements = (float*)malloc(B.width * B.height * sizeof(float));
    C.height = A.height;
    C.width = B.width;
    C.elements = (float*)malloc(C.width * C.height * sizeof(float));

    //populates arrays with random numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < A.height; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < A.width; j++)
            A.elements[i*A.width + j] = (float)(rand() % 3);
    for(int i = 0; i < B.height; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < B.width; j++)
            B.elements[i*B.width + j] = (float)(rand() % 2);
    MatrixMult(A, B, C);

    for(int i = 0; i < A.height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < A.width; j++)
            printf("%f ", A.elements[i*A.width + j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < B.height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < B.width; j++)
            printf("%f ", B.elements[i*B.width + j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < C.height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < C.width; j++)
            printf("%f ", C.elements[i*C.width + j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let's say the block size is 8x8, and you want to multiply A=3x4 with B=4x9. You  can embed the input matrices in block-sized matrices and pad the rest with zeroes, as that does not affect the results for the smaller matrices. So copy A to an 8x8 matrix and B to an 8x16 matrix. Then do the block-sized multiplication. Afterwards extract the useful pieces from the 8x16 result (3x9 in my example) and print them.

Comment: I understand the theory behind it, I am just unsure how to make that edit to the _main_ function

Comment: Remember the original width and height. Round up the `height` and `width` of your matrices to multiples of the block size. Allocate arrays with the padded size. Fill in the original part and set the padding to zero. Do the multiplication. Extract the useful portion of the output.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, although I don't understand what you mean about padding?

Comment: Taking my example above, you need to pad the matrix A=3x4 to the block size 8x8. The resulting matrix must be zero everywhere, except for the upper 3x4 part, which is a copy of A. The zeros are 'padding' as they are just taking up space and not relevant to the calculation of AxB.

Comment: I think, it could be interesting that you add the `cuda` tag (and/or mention it in the title). Your question will be visible to CUDA developers.